# How to Access Wifi MacAddress on latest Android devices Programmatically?

Tags: android, kotlin, wifi, ip-address, mac-address

I was looking for the attributes which make a wifi Access point unique from others so macAddress is one.

Now i'm trying to find the macAddress of connected wifi. I'm following this [article](https://robinhenniges.com/android-6-0-you-can-no-longer-access-the-mac-address-you-can/) which works on android 6.0 (author said) but getting an error on android 11 that `Attempt to get length of null array` on `i in 0..it.hardwareAddress.size`. which means hardwareAddress array is null.

**So how can we access MacAddress of Wifi on the latest android devices?**

below is the code i tried:

```
fun getMacAddress(): String {

        var stringMac = "default"
        try {

            val networkInterfaceList = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces())

            for (it in networkInterfaceList) {

                if (it.name.lowercase() == "wlan0") {
                    Log.d(TAG, "getMacAddress: Yes Equals")

                    for (i in 0..it.hardwareAddress.size) {
                        var stringMacByte =
                            Integer.toHexString((it.hardwareAddress[i] and 0xFF.toByte()).toInt())

                        if (stringMacByte.length == 1) {
                            stringMacByte = "0$stringMacByte"
                        }
                        stringMac = stringMac + stringMacByte.toUpperCase() + ":"
                    }
                    break
                }
            }


            return stringMac
        } catch (e: SocketException) {
            return stringMac
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change integer.toHexstring for  String.format("%02X", x), because when your mac_addr contains 0 (zero),   to convert to integer will be dissapear, and you will be got an 11 digits mac,  that its wrong,  it should be contain 12 chars;